# How to connect two observable and return true if they completes in Angular using RxJs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm creating a guard and I'm using `canActivate`. I'm also using `NgRx` state management.

Scenario:

If `materialState$` has data, return true
If `userCurrency$` has data, return true

I would like to connect them into one observable and if their both have data return true

My code:

```js
export class IsTrue implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private userFacade: UserFacade) {}
    
   canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      this.userFacade.getUserStatiscis();
    
      const materialState$ = this.userFacade.materialState$.pipe(
          filter((data) => data !== null),
          map((data) => {
             if (data) return true;
          }),
      );
    
      const userCurrency$ = this.userFacade.selectUserCurrency$.pipe(
          filter((data) => data !== null),
          map((data) => {
             if (data) return true;
          }),
      );
    
// return forkJoin(materialState$, userCurrency$);
    }
}
```

I've tried using `forkJoin`, `merge`, and `concat` but without success.

@Edit

I found a working "solution", could you rate that?

```js
      return combineLatest([materialState$, userCurrency$]).pipe(
            map((data) => {
                if (data) return true;
            }),
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `combineLatest` operator, then mapping the result to a `boolean`, like the following:

```js
combineLatest([
  this.userFacade.materialState$.pipe(filter(data => !!data)),
  this.userFacade.selectUserCurrency$.pipe(filter(data => !!data))
]).pipe(
  map(([materialState, userCurrency]) => !!materialState && !!userCurrency)
);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but your solution doesn't work for me. Guard is not letting me go.

Comment: It seems that your observables emitting some null values before emitting the correct data, so just try my update, please.

Comment: Yosuf i've tried your updated solution but guard still doesn't let go

Comment: Still that's not it. I had to add .pipe(filter((data) => !!data)) into both observables, and now it's working :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated it with `filter`, but then revert it back when you told me that it didn't work. Anyway, I reverted the last update and kept the answer with `filter`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to know is whether they both emitted at least one value `combineLatest` is your friend, because it only starts to emit after all sources emitted at least once.

```
combineLatest([
  this.userFacade.materialState$,
  this.userFacade.selectUserCurrency$
]);
```

if you explicitely need the true/false you can append

```
.pipe(
  map(() => true)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const materialState$ = this.userFacade.materialState$.pipe(
    filter(data => !!data)
);

const userCurrency$ = this.userFacade.selectUserCurrency$.pipe(
    filter((data) => !!data)
);


const connectedStream$ =  combineLatest([ materialState$, userCurrency$ ]);
```